# how to find which nested loop is excellent

Tags: powershell

I am struck at point where , i am not able to figure out which loop does the job .
To brief , i have an array on which i perform a activity on each item and the run time time is unexpected , so instead of waiting for all of them to complete , i just want to wait only till two items are completed and then proceed further and then comback again when another two items are available and so...on until the original array is completed .

edit1 : modified the code , now it need to go into the final loop and null the array and iterate from the beginning

```
$server_array = @('server1','server2','server3','server4','server5','server6')
$confirmed_array = @()
Foreach($server in $server_array )
{
#do copy 
#perform copy code of a file on $server  (i knew this code ) 
}

#validate below until the $server array is null means all the transfers are done 
#reason i am using while is to make sure the below loop waits until the file is transferred and to all the servers.
$server_array_count = $server_array.Count
while($server_array_count -ne 0 ) {
Foreach($server in $server_array )
{
$confirm_copy = $true

#Takes unexpected time , so instead of waiting to complete for all the servers i want to check whenever the two servers are done i want to perform the next steps . 

#wait until file is transferred atleast for 2 servers 

if ($confirm_copy)
{
#file transferred 
#add to new array so that i can use next block 
$confirmed_array += $server
$server_array_count -= 1
}
else
{
Write-Host "progress"
}
#$confirmed_array
$confirmed_array_count = $confirmed_array.Count
$confirmed_array_count 
}
if($confirm_array_count -eq 2)
{
#do next steps 
Write-Host "trigger"
$confirmed_array = @()
}

}
```

Comment: I think to answer this effectively, we'll have to know how you're executing the file copy. PowerShell is generally not executed asynchronously or in parallel, but there are ways to do so. The most common of which is via PowerShell Remoting sessions and jobs. But based on your current code, we need to either make that decision for you, or guess what you're doing, and that's not ideal. So if you could fill in some of those details, it would be quite helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, you would like to perform copy actions on two servers at a time and when done do next steps on those two servers.
Then iterate to do the same on the next two servers (or less if there is only one server left in the array)

If that is the case, you could do a simple numbered `for` loop like:

```
$server_array = 'server1','server2','server3','server4','server5','server6','server7'

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $server_array.Count; $i += 2) {
    # perform copy actions on two servers (if there are that many left)

    Write-Host "Copy to server '$($server_array[$i])'"
    # perform copy action
    if (($i + 1) -lt $server_array.Count) {
        Write-Host "Copy to server '$($server_array[$i + 1])'"
        # perform copy action
    }
    #do next steps  on two servers (if there are that many left)
    Write-Host "Trigger next steps on server '$($server_array[$i])'"
    # perform next step
    if (($i + 1) -lt $server_array.Count) {
        Write-Host "Trigger next steps on server '$($server_array[$i + 1])'"
        # perform next step
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Copy to server 'server1'
Copy to server 'server2'
Trigger next steps on server 'server1'
Trigger next steps on server 'server2'
Copy to server 'server3'
Copy to server 'server4'
Trigger next steps on server 'server3'
Trigger next steps on server 'server4'
Copy to server 'server5'
Copy to server 'server6'
Trigger next steps on server 'server5'
Trigger next steps on server 'server6'
Copy to server 'server7'
Trigger next steps on server 'server7'
```